# UDF in C# that updates a table (dividing all data with result of query)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

Is there a way to divide each data of a table (all columns and rows) by

```
select count(*) from table;
```

so for example

table

```
     a1  a2  a3   a4
   -------------------
    438 498 3625 3645
    500 291 5000 2351
    233 263 1298 1687
    198 117 1744 5932
    438 498 3625 3648
    500 291 5000 2637
```

and then divide each of them by 6 which is the number of rows

```
     a1    a2   a3      a4
   ------------------------
   73.0  83.0 604.16  607.5
   83.33 48.5 833.33  391.83
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

One problem is that my data are INT, but after transform they would be double...

In c# I was doing:

```
int N = 0;
string sql = @"select count(*) from 'ExampleTable'";
N  = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

int Columns = 0;
sql = @"select count(*) from information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ExampleTable'";

Columns  = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();


cmdLoad.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [ExampleTable]";
int i,j;
double[,] newTable  = new double[N, Columns];
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdLoad.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (reader.Read())
    {
        for ( i = 1; i <= N; j++)
        {
           for ( j = 1; j <= Columns; j++)
          {
              newTable[i,j] = reader.GetDouble((i*j) - 1) / N ;
          } //j  
        } //i
     }//reader
}
```

but I am not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the columns in advance, it's pretty easy:

```
SELECT 
    a1 / Rows As a1, 
    a2 / Rows As a2, 
    a3 / Rows As a3, 
    a4 / Rows As a4
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, CAST(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) as float) As Rows
    FROM ExampleTable
) Data
```

If not, you'll need to do effectively what you're doing in C# - loop through the columns and build a dynamic query

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)
DECLARE @Query varchar(max)
SELECT @TableName = 'ExampleTable'
SELECT @Query = 'SELECT '
SELECT @Query = @Query + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] / Rows as [' + COLUMN_NAME + '], '
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS col WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName

SELECT @Query = @Query + 'Rows FROM ( SELECT *, CAST(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) as float) As Rows FROM [' + @TableName + ']) Data'
EXECUTE(@Query)
```